# Spark SQL COALESCE

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have extracted the coalesce value from a table using Spark SQL. Then I'm converting the result to String so that I can INSERT that value into another table.

However, the column name of the COALESCE is getting inserted into the table instead of the coalesce value.

These are my COALESCE and INSERT queries,

```
COALESCE:
---------

val lastPartition = spark.sql("SELECT COALESCE(MAX(partition_name), 'XXXXX') FROM db1.table1").toString.mkString

Result:
-------

COALESCE(MAX(partition_name),XXXXX
            20210309



INSERT:
-------

val result = spark.sql(s"""INSERT INTO db2.table2 VALUES ('col1','col2','${lastPartition}','col4')""")


Result:
--------

col1     col2                       col3                                 col4
1        John    [COALESCE(MAX(partition_name),XXXXX):string]        15313.21
```

Here, I want the value of column (col3) to be 20210309 and not the coalesce column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.head().getString(0)` to get the string as the variable. Otherwise, if you use `.toString`, you'll get the expression instead because of lazy evaluation.

```
val lastPartition = spark.sql("SELECT COALESCE(MAX(partition_name), 'XXXXX') FROM db1.table1").head().getString(0)
```